# ASP.NET Displaying image acording to the correct ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a school project and I'm trying to display a image for each product in my ASP.NET application. However I've been on this issue the whole day and I can't seem to find a fix.

In my controller I have this code for loading all the products for each category and image data:

```cs
public IActionResult GetProducts(int id)
{
    var model = new ShoppingCartModel
    {
        Products = service.GetProducts().Where(c => c.CategoryID == id),
            Categories = categoriesService.GetCategories(),
            Images = imageService.GetImages(),
            ProductImages = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    };

    foreach (var product in model.Products)
    {
        var image = model.Images.FirstOrDefault(img => img.ImageID == product.ImageID);

        if (image != null)
        {
            model.ProductImages.Add(product.ProductID, image.ImagePath);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I load all the data from the database into the `Images` which is a `IEnumerable`. The table contains a `ImageID` and a `ImagePath` data looks like this '1' | 'images/filename.png'. Each product has a `ImageID` linked to it:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Images>? Images { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, string> ProductImages { get; set; }
```

All files are in my `wwwroot` folder in my ASP.NET project. So `wwwroot/images/filename.png`. My model also has a `ProductImages` which is a `Dictionary<int, string>` which I will use to find the correct imagePath for the product.

I then loop in all the products in the `foreach`, and find the correct image for each product and add them to the dictionary.

Then I have this in my view:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    @if (Model.ProductImages.ContainsKey(item.ProductID))
    {
      var imagePath = Model.ProductImages[item.ProductID];
      <img src="@imagePath" alt="Product Image"/>
    }
}
```

When I replace the `src` with `src="images/filename.png"` it does work. I already debugged to see what `imagePath` was and it's the correct `imagePath`. I have no idea why it's not working. I've also tried doing it with JavaScript and then passing the path back into the `src` but no luck.

I'd appreciate any help with this! :)

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on where your View is. Try to specify a relative path not from the current directory, but from the root directory. The path must start with /, for example: "/images/filename.jpg"

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    @if (Model.ProductImages.ContainsKey(item.ProductID))
    {
       var imagePath = $"/{Model.ProductImages[item.ProductID]}";
       <img src="@imagePath" alt="Product Image"/>
    }
}
```

Please copy here `<img src="@imagePath" alt="Product Image"/>`, from source code of your browser, after page generated.